# Passing data from Ajax Post to node js

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am learning node and want to send some data from an Ajax call to node.

Below are my Ajax and node calls.

Ajax Method

```
function getUserName(){
    var data ={};
    data.email=$('#email').val();
    data.fNmame=$('#fNmame').val();
    data.lName=$('#lName').val();

    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        data: JSON.stringify(data),
        contentType: "application/json",
        dataType:'json',
        url: '/getUserName',                      
        success: function(data) {
            console.log('success');
            console.log(JSON.stringify(data));                               
        },
        error: function(error) {
            console.log("some error in fetching the notifications");
         }
    });
}
```

Node function

```
app.post('/getUserName',function(req,res){

        var reqData =  JSON.stringify(req.params);

        console.log("reqData :::: " + reqData);

    });
```

In the logs I can see

```
reqData :::: {}
```

Please suggest.

Comment: var reqData =  JSON.parse(req.body); will work for you.

Answer (score 1):

The `POST` data is received in `req.body`.
`req.params` is used for dynamic parameters.
For `/users/:id`, you'd get the value of `id` in `req.params`. 
Try using `req.body` for `POST` body data.

Comment: changed from req.params to req.body and the output changed to reqData :::: undefined

Comment: Are you using `express`? I'm assuming you are. Do you have the `body-parser` middleware? It's hard to say with only this code and is required for Express 4+

Comment: I am using express 4.15

Comment: I am not using a form submit. On button click I want to make an ajax call.

Answer (score 0):

Finally found the answer I was not using `app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded( { extended: false } ));` because of which post was not working as expected.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make use of body-parser middleware for extracting data from post request. You could do it this way:

```
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({
    extended: true
}));

app.post('/getUserName',function(req,res){

    var reqData =  JSON.stringify(req.body.data);

    console.log("reqData :::: " + reqData);

});
```

To extract data you need to get data as req.body.data and not req.params. This is used to get dynamic variables from your get route.